# How to change colors for shadow vertical lines in a candlestick chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a comprehensive finance chart that I can use to analyze historical & current prices.  I've already finished the project but the problem I have is with the vertical lines that appear in the middle of each candlestick.  It is somehow defaulted to black (you can't see with black background color) and I want to change this color to colorup and colordown.  So I went and tried to modify finance.py in matplotlib library by moving vLine code to if/else statement in _candlestick function and modifying appropriately.  It looks like this:

```
def candlestick(ax, quotes, width=0.2, colorup='k', colordown='r',
                alpha=1.0):
    warnings.warn(_warn_str.format(fun='candlestick'),
                  mplDeprecation)

    return _candlestick(ax, quotes, width=width, colorup=colorup,
                        colordown=colordown,
                        alpha=alpha, ochl=True)

def _candlestick(ax, quotes, width=0.2, colorup='k', colordown='r',
                alpha=1.0, ochl=True):
 OFFSET = width / 2.0

    lines = []
    patches = []
    for q in quotes:
        if ochl:
            t, open, close, high, low = q[:5]
        else:
            t, open, high, low, close = q[:5]

        if close >= open:
            color = colorup
            lower = open
            height = close - open
            vline = Line2D(
                xdata=(t, t), ydata=(low, high),
                color=colorup,
                linewidth=0.5,
                antialiased=True,
                )       
        else:
            color = colordown
            lower = close
            height = open - close
            vline = Line2D(
                xdata=(t, t), ydata=(low, high),
                color=colordown,
                linewidth=0.5,
                antialiased=True,
                )            
'''
        vline = Line2D(
            xdata=(t, t), ydata=(low, high),
            color=color,
            linewidth=0.5,
            antialiased=True,
            )
'''
        rect = Rectangle(
            xy=(t - OFFSET, lower),
            width = width,
            height = height,
            facecolor = color,
            edgecolor = color,
            )
        rect.set_alpha(alpha)

        lines.append(vline)
        patches.append(rect)
        ax.add_line(vline)
        ax.add_patch(rect)
    ax.autoscale_view()

    return lines, patches
```

and then I called this function in my main code:

```
candlestick(ax1, candleAr[-SP:], width=.75, colorup='#53C156', colordown='#ff1717')
```

I get the same result as if I didn't make any changes.  What should I do?  Please help.

Thanks for posting first of all.  My points are not high enough for me to upload the resulting figure, so I'll just show you the code that shows one of the analysis that's shown in the figure:

```
def graphData(stock,MA1,MA2):
    try:
        try:
            print 'Currently Pulling data for:', stock
            print str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time())).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
            urlToVisit = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/'+stock+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv'
            stockFile = []
            try:
                sourceCode = urllib2.urlopen(urlToVisit).read()
                splitSource = sourceCode.split('\n')
                for eachLine in splitSource:
                    splitLine = eachLine.split(',')
                    if len(splitLine)==6:
                        if 'values' not in eachLine:
                            stockFile.append(eachLine)

            except Exception, e:
                print str(e), 'failed to organize pulled data'


        except Exception, e:
            print str(e), 'failed to pull price data'

        #stockFile = stock+'.txt'

        date, closep, highp, lowp, openp, volume = np.loadtxt(stockFile, delimiter=',', unpack=True, converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d')})

        x = 0
        y = len(date)
        candleAr = []
        while x < y:
            appendLine = date[x],openp[x],closep[x],highp[x],lowp[x],volume[x]
            candleAr.append(appendLine)
            x+=1

        Av1 = movingaverage(closep, MA1)
        Av2 = movingaverage(closep, MA2)

        SP = len(date[MA2-1:])

        fig = plt.figure(facecolor='#07000d')

        ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,4), (1,0), rowspan=4, colspan=4, axisbg='#07000d')
        candlestick(ax1, candleAr[-SP:], width=.75, colorup='#53C156', colordown='#ff1717')

        label1 = str(MA1)+'  SMA'           
        label2 = str(MA2)+'  SMA'
        ax1.plot(date[-SP:],Av1[-SP:],'#e1edf9',label=label1, linewidth = 1.5)
        ax1.plot(date[-SP:],Av2[-SP:],'#4ee6fd',label=label2, linewidth = 1.5)  

        ax1.grid(True, color='w')
        ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(10))
        ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
        plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(prune='upper'))
        plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(prune='lower'))
        ax1.yaxis.label.set_color('w')
        ax1.spines['bottom'].set_color('#5998ff')
        ax1.spines['top'].set_color('#5998ff')      
        ax1.spines['right'].set_color('#5998ff')        
        ax1.spines['left'].set_color('#5998ff') 
        ax1.tick_params(axis='y', colors='w')   
        ax1.tick_params(axis='x', colors='w')   
        plt.ylabel('Stock Price and Volume')
```

and so on.  You get the idea.

Comment: Could you provide a *complete* example of how your `candlestick` function will be called? Perhaps something that generates some random data to produce some figure. Bonus points for including the resulting figure in your question so we can immediately see what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for posting Rodin.  I added more stuff to my original question to make it more clear.

Comment: I have actually found a solution to this.  I had to look in my system library.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are editing the correct finance.py file. I know on my computer there are two copies of the files. Take the 'vline = ...' out of the 'if' and 'else' statment and uncomment the vline block of code. My edited file has:

```
def candlestick(ax, quotes, width=0.2, colorup='k', colordown='r',
            alpha=1.0, color='k'):

    return _candlestick(ax, quotes, width=width, colorup=colorup,
                        colordown=colordown,
                        alpha=alpha, ochl=True)

def _candlestick(ax, quotes, width=0.2, colorup='k', colordown='r',
                 alpha=1.0, ochl=True):
     OFFSET = width / 2.0

    lines = []
    patches = []
    for q in quotes:
        if ochl:
            t, open, close, high, low = q[:5]
        else:
            t, open, high, low, close = q[:5]

        if close >= open:
            color = colorup
            lower = open
            height = close - open
        else:
            color = colordown
            lower = close
            height = open - close

        vline = Line2D(
            xdata=(t, t), ydata=(low, high),
            color=color,
            linewidth=0.5,
            antialiased=True,
        )

        rect = Rectangle(
            xy=(t - OFFSET, lower),
            width = width,
            height = height,
            facecolor = color,
            edgecolor = color,
        )
        rect.set_alpha(alpha)

        lines.append(vline)
        patches.append(rect)
        ax.add_line(vline)
        ax.add_patch(rect)
    ax.autoscale_view()

    return lines, patches
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSyMaJPOfX8 walks you through the process. If you are still having trouble let me know.